# How to check the device OS version from Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

`Platform.operatingSystem` will tell you whether you're running on Android or iOS.

How can I check which version of the device OS am I running on?

Answer (score 151):

**Note:
This package is discontinued. Use this [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) instead.**

Add this plugin to your pubspec [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info)

Human-readable way is

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  var androidInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
  var release = androidInfo.version.release;
  var sdkInt = androidInfo.version.sdkInt;
  var manufacturer = androidInfo.manufacturer;
  var model = androidInfo.model;
  print('Android $release (SDK $sdkInt), $manufacturer $model');
  // Android 9 (SDK 28), Xiaomi Redmi Note 7
}

if (Platform.isIOS) {
  var iosInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().iosInfo;
  var systemName = iosInfo.systemName;
  var version = iosInfo.systemVersion;
  var name = iosInfo.name;
  var model = iosInfo.model;
  print('$systemName $version, $name $model');
  // iOS 13.1, iPhone 11 Pro Max iPhone
}
```

Comment: The plugin got replaced by device_info_plus https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus

Comment: import 'dart:io'; - needs to be added for making condition with Platform. Otherwise Platform is not recognized.

Answer (score 19):

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

void main() {
  // Get the operating system as a string.
  String os = Platform.operatingSystem;
  // Or, use a predicate getter.
  if (Platform.isMacOS) {
    print('is a Mac');
  } else {
    print('is not a Mac');
  }
}
```

[Dart SDK > dart:io > Platform](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-io/Platform-class.html)

Here is  the official article above, and if you want to check it is IOS or Andriod,
you can use:

```
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  print('is a IOS');
} else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  print('is a Andriod');
} else {
}
```

Here's how to get the iOS version

```
  print(Platform.operatingSystem); // "ios"
  print(Platform.operatingSystemVersion); // "Version 15.5 (Build 19F70)"
```

Caveat: The documentation says the OS version string is not suitable for parsing since it doesn't follow a standard format. However, if you test it for the versions you're interested in, you should be fine. E.g. you could test it on iOS versions 13, 14, and 15 and the string returned will always be the same for the specific versions tested. I am guessing the packages that provide version info use this string and apply some smart parsing to it to figure out the actual OS version.

Comment: OP is asking for operating system version number not the name of operating system.

Comment: Don't know hot this answer has so many upvotes. It clearly doesn't reply the OP question

Answer (score 7):

You can use [platform channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) for this task. In native use os specific code to get version and resend it to flutter. Here is good [example](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/#example) with battery level

Answer (score 7):

You can use `dart:io`

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

String osVersion = Platform.operatingSystemVersion;
```

Comment: Please note that this isn't a good aproach if you use this information for anything other than logging. From the [docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.0/dart-io/Platform/operatingSystemVersion.html): `The format of this string will vary by operating system, platform and version and is not suitable for parsing.` Empathis on '**not suitable for parsing**'

Comment: `Platform.operatingSystemVersion` return `QP1A.190711.020 release-keys`. I need OS version, but what just i get ?

Answer (score 1):

In my usecase I want to limit access to a native functionality to specifc OS versions. For that I've wrote a library that allows you to specify the supported versions for a certain part of your code.

If that covers your usecase check out the library: https://pub.dev/packages/available

```
import 'package:available/available.dart';


Future<void> doPlatformSpecificThing() async {
  if(await available(ios: const OSRequirement(min: 14))) {
    // this call will only be executed on iOS >= 14
    doPlatformSpecficiThing();
  }
}
```

If you want to determine the OS version only please have a look on the [`VersionResolver` class](https://github.com/jonasfranz/available/blob/90283174a126cc2b6fd0ef0a157c43f8ba3accff/lib/src/version_resolver.dart) that uses [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) to parse the OS version.