# Detecting app run on emulator or real device

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to detect, if an app is running on an iOS or Android emulator to skip an QR code scan method and just return a scanned code.

**Q: How do I detect**

- on which **device type** - iOS or Android - an app is running and
- if an app is running on an **emulator**?

Comment: Why not having a configuration that skips QRcode; and use that configuration on emulators ?

Comment: A little bit of searching could have provided you the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45300661/how-to-check-the-device-os-version-from-flutter. The package mentioned there provides a way to check whether you are running on a physical device

Comment: @RuudKobes Sorry, did search. But failed to find a solution reasonably quick.

Comment: @RémiRousselet I'd like to decide dynamically. Besides the emulator/real device question, I do need other details too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found this plugin, which prints various details:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/device_info#-readme-tab-

Output on Android emulator [see last line]:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[safe_device: ^1.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/safe_device)

```
import 'package:safe_device/safe_device.dart';
```

Checks whether device is real or emulator

```
bool isRealDevice = await SafeDevice.isRealDevice;
```

(ANDROID ONLY) Check if development Options is enable on device

```
bool isDevelopmentModeEnable = await SafeDevice.isDevelopmentModeEnable;
```