# How can I tell if my app is running on MIUI os?

Tags: flutter, miui

`Platform.operatingSystem` only returns android and you can't really tell from `Platform.operatingSystemVersion` if it's MIUI either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45300661/how-to-check-the-device-os-version-from-flutter

Comment: Using https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus I can only tell the manufacturer. So I guess trying to tell by manufacturer will have to suffice for now...

Comment: OR it might be possible using https://gist.github.com/Muyangmin/e8ec1002c930d8df3df46b306d03315d and method channels, but it seems like overkill.